# AssetHub interaction with AccountId20

Tags: xcm, evm, assets, accountid, mapping

Say I want to send and receive tokens from AssetHub in my chain that is using AccountId20 format to interact with internal pallets. I understand that Rococo uses AccountId32 so how would I go about configuring that mapping between accounts to allow an EVM format account to interact with AssetHub and a compatible substrate account there?

Should I have a pallet that handles that mapping or an XCM configuration that solves it, what would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You could check [moonbeam xcm_config](https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/blob/master/runtime/moonbeam/src/xcm_config.rs#L109-L112) or [darwinia xcm_config](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/v6.5.1/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/polkadot_xcm.rs#L86-L89). Both of them using AccountId20 format.

The type [`LocationToAccountId`](https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/blob/v0.35.0/runtime/moonbeam/src/xcm_config.rs#L104) specifying how a `MultiLocation` can be converted into an `AccountId`.

The type [`LocalOriginToLocation`](https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/blob/v0.35.0/runtime/moonbeam/src/xcm_config.rs#L345) specifying how a signed local origin into a MultiLocation.

In general, `LocationToAccountId` and `LocalOriginToLocation` is enough, I don't think a pallet is needed to handle it.